# gtkmm: moving a calendar on an overlay (cropping issue)

Tags: c++, calendar, gtk, overlay, gtkmm

using Ubuntu 14.04 with libgtkmm-3.0-dev

I have a calendar widget sitting on an overlay container. Without changing anything, the calendar will appear in the top left corner of the overlay. I'd like to move the calendar down slightly but the bottom keeps getting cut off.

See below for some example code which will demonstrate the problem. if you change "newAlloc.set_y(30);" to "newAlloc.set_y(0);", there will be no cropping issues but of course the calendar will return to the top.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

void CalendarSizeAllocate(Gtk::Allocation alloc, Gtk::Calendar * cal)
{
    Gtk::Allocation newAlloc = alloc;
    newAlloc.set_y(30);
    cal->set_allocation(newAlloc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(300, 300);

    GtkWidget * Overlay = gtk_overlay_new();
    window.add(*Glib::wrap(Overlay));

    Gtk::Box box;
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Overlay), GTK_WIDGET(box.gobj()));  

    Gtk::Calendar * calendar = new Gtk::Calendar();
    calendar->set_valign(Gtk::ALIGN_START);
    calendar->signal_size_allocate().connect(sigc::bind<Gtk::Calendar*>(sigc::ptr_fun(&CalendarSizeAllocate), calendar));
    gtk_overlay_add_overlay(GTK_OVERLAY(Overlay), GTK_WIDGET(calendar->gobj()));

    window.show_all();
    app->run(window);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## FIX:

For overlay item placement; You have to use margins for precision placement; and **H**Align and **V**Align for generic placement.

```cs
calendar->set_margin_top(30); // This will push the calendar 30 pixels(?) down from the top.
```

You also shouldn't need to set the allocation size manually; you can use `set_size_request(width, height)` instead.

## More details here:

[Overlay Description](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Overlay.html#details)

[Set Margin](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a048393c3adfbf1caac68d4094b0209a4)